# validar campo checkbox - javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un campo checkbox en mi formulario pero necesito que el formulario no se envié hasta que el checkbox este seleccionado, he intentado pero no he logrado hacer esta validación:

```js
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="reset">
    <div class="form-group form-check">
<div class="col-md-7">
            
            <label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control required" autocomplete="off"  required>
</div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="conditions" name="conditions">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="conditions">Aceptar condiciones de uso</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="reset" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Esto no lo puedes hacer con PHP, debes ocupar javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bastaría con poner `required` en tu checkbox, así indicas que el checkbox es requerido y debe estar seleccionado para que el formulario se envíe.

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="conditions" name="conditions" required>
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="reset">
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control required" autocomplete="off"  required>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="conditions" name="conditions" required> 
    <label class="form-check-label" for="conditions">Aceptar condiciones de uso</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="reset" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```